# How to eliminate the margin of div boxes

Tags: html, css

I created a few div and gave some colours to it in order to see the difference on changes as I code and see that there is a big white spacing between each box.
How can I remove these white spaces?

Here my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/8tgLzjeq/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<ul>
  <li><a id="deposit" href="#">Deposit</a></li>
  <li><a id="account" href="#">Account</a></li>
  <li><a id="credit" href="#">Credit</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="box deposit">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sunt voluptates reprehenderit similique nostrum eius repudiandae odio eos obcaecati doloremque quam quos, officiis veritatis blanditiis soluta molestiae iusto illo corrupti.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="box account">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sunt voluptates reprehenderit similique nostrum eius repudiandae odio eos obcaecati doloremque quam quos, officiis veritatis blanditiis soluta molestiae iusto illo corrupti.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="box credit">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sunt voluptates reprehenderit similique nostrum eius repudiandae odio eos obcaecati doloremque quam quos, officiis veritatis blanditiis soluta molestiae iusto illo corrupti.</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="random">
  <p>This is a random text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
li{
  list-style:none;
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover{
      color: blue;
    }  
  }
}
ul{
  background: black;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box{
  height: 200px; 
}
.deposit{
  background-color: green;
}
.account{
  background: pink;
}
.credit{
  background: blue;
}
li a.active{
  color: red;
}
```

Hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `p` margins and replace them with paddings if needed: `p{margin:0;}`

Comment: I added that. But it didnt solve for all the boxes. Please check my updated snippet.
https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/8tgLzjeq/5/

Comment: Actually it works yes. I added margin 0 to the ul as well and voalla.

Comment: also lists have by default left padding